# Giving single parameter having commas to SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-foxpro

I am using visual FoxPro and SQL. I am creating reports in visual Foxpro using SQL data. All connections are set.
here is one store procedure and I want to give parameter like

```
@A=''AA','BB','CC''
```

but because of comma it acts like separate parameters to procedure
that is used for IN operator
eg. `where V_TYPE in (@A)`

Parameter value come from Visual FoxPro.''AA','BB','CC'' by the VFP program.
this is single parameter for Stored procedure.
eg. EXEC testProc ''AA','BB','CC'' . 
but because of comma its act like three para .
Is there problem with quotes ??seeting of quoted identifier

please tell me how should I give parameter like this.
thanks in Advance!

Comment: You will have to use dynamic sql for this. There are lots of examples you can find if you google it

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you have been given advices that you shouldn't use at all and wide open to SQL injection attacks. Instead there are multiple safe ways to do that.
One of them is to create a temp table in SQL server, insert values there and use inner join instead of an IN query.
One another way is to use a procedure to parse comma separated values to a table server side and use it in a join.
Yet another way is to pass an XML data string, create table at server side and do a join. Below is a sample using XML (for the other 2 samples look here - [samples](http://www.fox4um.com/topic/1090/son-zamanlarda-gordugum-en-iyi-kodlardan-birisi/)):

```
 LOCAL lnHandle, cXML, myInQuery

TEXT TO myInQuery noshow
DECLARE @hDoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, ?m.cXML

SELECT * FROM [Northwind]..[Products] 
WHERE ProductID IN 
(
    SELECT myID FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, ?m.cNodename, 1) WITH (myid int)
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

ENDTEXT


** Local cursor
CREATE CURSOR test (myID i)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5)
** Local cursor

CURSORTOXML('test','cXML',2)

cNodeName = '/VFPData/test' && CursorToXML by default use VFPData as root, and tablename in lowercase for rows

lnHandle = SQLSTRINGCONNECT('Driver={SQL Native Client};server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes')
SQLEXEC(m.lnHandle, m.myInQuery, 'result')
SQLDISCONNECT(m.lnHandle)

SELECT result
BROWSE
```

Note: With these types of approaches your values could be any type without the worry of having quotes or other characters in it (int, char, datetime ...).